# How to disable dates in a datepicker fields based on values in several fields?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, onchange, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have several text-type input fields filled by dates. Those fields are added dynamically, depending on database contents. Each field has its own id: multi_datepicker_0, multi_datepicker_1, multi_datepicker_2, and so on, and each of them (besides one) has a date value. I need to disable dates which are values in all fields together.
I would like this change to take place when document is ready and also any field is modified.
My code is like that:

```
$(function(){
  var dateArray = [];
      
  $('input[id^=multi_datepicker_]').each(function(){
    dateArray.push($(this).val());
  });
      
  $('input[id^=multi_datepicker_]').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
      var day = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', date);
      return [ dateArray.indexOf(day) == -1 ]
    }
  });

});
```

It works well, but once, only on ready document, not on a datefield change.
Can I count on your help?

Comment: Can you tell us *which* datepicker you are using?   As they are all very similar, but subtly different.  It doesn't look like you have an event for "when any field is modified".

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm not sure what you mean of _which_ datepicker, but I use the jQuery UI - v1.13.0. I agree. I haven't got any event for changing fields, because I have got no idea how to apply it in my case.